# how to list specific user/subscriber by username with his/her avatar and with a message on a page/post?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a contest on my site. So I am creating hall of fame page where I can display contest winner users with their avatars and name and with a congratulation message. Can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get_users() function to fetch users based on any particular criteria. More info about this function is on [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

This function will return you an array. You can loop through this array to print the user list.

And to get the avatar pics of the user, use get_avatar($id_or_email) function.